# How can I ensure that I am not missing something in malloc and free?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-allocation

```
char **test() {
    char **res = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);
    for (int cur = 0; cur < 3; cur++) {
        char *str = (char *)malloc(10);
        strcpy(str, "Maneger");
        res[cur] = (char *)malloc(strlen(str));
        strcpy(res[cur], str);
        free(str);
    }
    res[3] = NULL;
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **li = test();
    //some code
    free(li);
    return 1;
}
```

What is wrong with `free()` in above code. Is it correct?

Comment: if you are using C++ don't use `malloc`. If you are using C, don't tag this as C++

Comment: You just forgot to free some pointers. (And should cast malloc return pointer)

Comment: Each `malloc` call should have a matching `free` call. You have three calls to `malloc` but only two to `free`. One of the `malloc`/`free` pairs you have is not needed by the way.

Comment: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Allocating `strlen(str)` bytes is not enough for copying `str`: you must allocate one more element for the terminating null character.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allocate space for the terminating null character.

The line

```
res[cur]=(char *)malloc(strlen(str));
```

should be

```
res[cur]=(char *)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

Also checking for return values ofr `malloc()` not to be `NULL` should be added.

Answer (score 1):

The free in main is not correct. It only frees the memory allocated to li pointer not the memory allocated to the array of pointer associated with it.

After freeing the li pointer the memory allocated to the array of pointer associated with it will become inaccessible which in wrong.

The correct way to free all memory is following :

```
free(li[0]);
free(li[1]);
free(li[2]);
```

And after this statements there should be:

```
free(li);
```

Hope it will help !!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- why do you allocate space for 5 pointers but only use 4?
- why do you allocate 10 bytes for `str`, copy a string to it, duplicate that and free str for every iteration?
- you do not allocate space for the null terminator in the copy of `"Maneger"`.
- you do not free the strings in `li`.
- you do not check for potential `malloc` failures.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void free_test(char **a) {
    if (a) {
        for (int i = 0; a[i]; i++) {
            free(a[i]);
        }
        free(a);
    }
}

char **test(void) {
    char **res = malloc(sizeof(*res) * 4);
    if (res) {
        int cur;
        for (cur = 0; cur < 3; cur++) {
            res[cur] = strdup("Maneger");
            if (res[cur] == NULL) {
                free_test(res);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        res[cur] = NULL;
    }
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **li = test();
    if (li == NULL)
        return 1;
    //some code
    free_test(li);
    return 0;
}
```

`strdup()` is a much simpler and safer way to duplicate strings. It is not part of Standard C, but supported on Posix and other systems.  If it is not available on your system, it can be redefined this way:

```
char *strdup(const char *s) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *p = malloc(len + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, s, len + 1);
    }
    return p;
}
```